# Mockito in Micronaut and kotin not working

Tags: kotlin, mockito, micronaut

Somehow I'm not able to mock via mockito a method and getting null pointer. Not sure why its failing!

```
import io.github.xxxx.repository.ProductRepository
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.bson.Document
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
open class OrderServiceTest {

    @field:Inject
    lateinit var productRepository: ProductRepository

    @Test
    fun name() {
        assertThat(2+3).isEqualTo(5)
        //  here I'm getting the error, The method is of type T? so returning null is ok
        `when`(productRepository.find("abc")).thenReturn(null);
         assertThat(productRepository.find("abc")).isNull()
    }

    @MockBean(ProductRepository::class)
    open fun contextService(): ProductRepository {
        return mock(ProductRepository::class.java)
    }
}
```

The exception that I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.github.imalik8088.repository.ProductRepository.getCollection(ProductRepository.kt:65)
    at io.github.imalik8088.repository.ProductRepository.find(ProductRepository.kt:40)
    at io.github.imalik8088.service.OrderServiceTest.name(OrderServiceTest.kt:22)
```

#### Addition/Solution/Findings:

- I found that [Kotest](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#kotest) the way to go with Micronaut framework and kotlin AFAIU Not if testcontainers with the junit extentions that I'm using is working with that
- mockk for mocking because native and idiomatic. Mockito has issues with final classes AFAIK e.g. Spring-Boot solves it with a lib that internally added `open` keyword to Kotlin classes
- Found also somehow the [docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#junit5) incomplete or not very precise there imports or methods used from kotest that are deprecated and in the source code it mentioned to use kotest..
- For the side that I'm doing it is not very important busy for a production critical it would helpful - my 2cents ... could be also lack of knowledge in the Framework and language (noob status for both :) )

Answer (score 1):

if you working with kotlin i recommend you to use mockk (https://mockk.io/) quite similar to mockito but using the full featureset of kotlins dsl. Regarding your problem, from the stacktrace it seems to me, that the mock does not work. Workin with repos i always recommend to use testcontainer and not mock the repos, cause in reality it could cause a lot of trouble, when the generated sql not works as expected.

But if you want to mock your repo and run some tests on that.
Forget about @MicronautTest and just mock the interface like that:

```
internal class OrderServiceTest {

private val  productRepository: ProductRepository = mock(ProductRepository::class.java)

@Test
fun name() {
    assertThat(2+3).isEqualTo(5)
    `when`(productRepository.find("abc")).thenReturn(null);
     assertThat(productRepository.find("abc")).isNull()
}
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks for your input, that helped. I'll update my question with the summary what I did. I've already found some more insights reading the docs. I've used now mockk for the test. I'm with your regarding the test. My idea is to use or I've already testcontainers inplace for @Repository tests but wanted to keep the Service Tests little bit fast. Sometimes I find the testcontainers tests quite slow.. -.-

Comment: yeah thats true regarding testcontainers .. thats why i eigther do simple unit tests without anything or the 'micronauttests' using testcontainers on a more higher level .. nevertheless from my experience the most time is spend on building the code ;-)

Comment: Nevertheless, regaring your initial problem .. i think its about your repo i tested it with eighter a repository as interface and also as abstract class, both worked with mockk just the way you wrote your test. i think you did something wrong within the repo